# Are there learning-to-rank algorithms that would maximize the Mean Reciprocal Rank (MRR) of a ranking result?

Tags: information-retrieval

I need to rank a list of true/false statements and I want as many true statements to be placed in the top, say, N positions as possible. Since more true statements being included in the top positions will lead to larger mean reciprocal rank (MRR) values, I'm looking for an algorithm that maximizes MRR. I know there are point-wise, pair-wise, and list-wise learning-to-rank algorithms, but none of them seem to optimize MRR.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: MRR only optimizes for the position of the most highly-ranked relevant document. Going after an algorithm that optimizes NDCG (list-wise) will be better; even if you're optimizing for MRR -- it uses an exponential discount. It also matches your desire for "as many true statements to be in the top [...] N positions as possible"

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your reply. In my case, the order among true statements or false statements is not important. For example, suppose we have two true statements (i.e., t1 and t2) and two false statements (i.e., f1 and f2). List [t1, t2, f1, f2] would be same for me as list [t2, t1, f2, f1]. Somehow, I had the (mis)impression that list-wise approaches handle such cases in a different way than I expect. I just read about NDCG and it does look like a better choice. Thanks again!